# PPTP VPN on Windows 10 terminates with Event ID 20226 and termination code 829

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, pptp, qnap

I have Windows 10 (OS build 17763) where I have created the PPTP VPN connection to the QNAP device following [this article](https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/how-to-set-up-and-use-qvpn-2-0). Unfortunately, the connection cannot be established.
In the App Event Log I can see the following RasClient events:

```
Event ID 20221 - CoId={9A9B6463-F59A-4806-B201-5861E839DAC4}: The user SYSTEM has started dialing a VPN connection using a per-user connection profile named myVPN. The connection settings are....

Event ID 20222 - CoId={9A9B6463-F59A-4806-B201-5861E839DAC4}: The user SYSTEM is trying to establish a link to the Remote Access Server for the connection named myVPN using the following device ... 

Event ID 20223 - CoId={9A9B6463-F59A-4806-B201-5861E839DAC4}: The user SYSTEM has successfully established a link to the Remote Access Server using the following device...

Event ID 20224 - CoId={9A9B6463-F59A-4806-B201-5861E839DAC4}: The link to the Remote Access Server has been established by user SYSTEM.

Event ID 20226 - The user AzureAD\[my_user_name] dialed a connection named myVPN which has terminated. The reason code returned on termination is 829.
```

I have done what follows without success:

1. Uninstalled the ESET Internet Security, reboot the computer, disable all windows firewall,
2. Found [this article](https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/knowledge-base/article/how-to-fix-the-issue-of-windows-10-not-connecting-to-ipsecl2tp-vpn-servers/) at QNAP forum. Applied the registry settings and rebooted the computer,
3. Removed and recreated the VPN connection,
4. Did a full TCP/IP stack reset

I have created the same VPN connection on another Windows 10 (OS Build 17134) computer and I can connect without any problems and efforts.

Do you have any tips/tricks I can use to solve or troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Is there a firewall or NAT device between the VPN user and this computer? It may be blocking part of the connection. Often the GRE protocol needs special handling. BTW, PPTP is terribly insecure...

Comment: Why does Windows 10 even have a PPTP client? PPTP was broken, and deprecated by Microsoft, well before Windows 10 came out.

Comment: I forgot to mention that one of the troubleshooting steps I connected the computer over the LTE connection from the phone. This didn’t work as well.